# DatePeriod recursive on non-valid month dates

Tags: php, date, recursion, subscription

I'm using DatePeriod in order to obtain a list of recursive dates for a recurring billing system.

Code example:

```
$time = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', 1496185200));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$occ = 3;
$period = new DatePeriod($time, $interval, $occ);

foreach($period as $d)
{
    echo $d->format('d/m/Y H:i').'<br>';
}
```

With the output:

```
31/05/2017 00:00
01/07/2017 00:00
01/08/2017 00:00
01/09/2017 00:00
```

If the transaction was purchased on the 31st May, the DatePeriod method will iterate to 1st July as the next valid date (no 31st June), however, I would need the dates on-going dates to return to the 31st for August etc.

So the output would be:

```
31/05/2017 00:00 (June payment)
01/07/2017 00:00 (July payment)
31/07/2017 00:00 (August payment)
31/08/2017 00:00 (September payment)
01/10/2017 00:00 (October payment)
31/10/2017 00:00 (November payment)
01/12/2017 00:00 (December payment)
31/12/2017 00:00 (January payment)
```

I'm struggling to calculate how to ensure the payment date is the next valid date. If the date is invalid, payment cannot be taken before the scheduled date, similar to Direct Debits.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you consistently use the last day of the month, instead of some complicated rule like *use the last day if the month has 31 days, otherwise use the first day of the next month*.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very elegant solution, but the below provides the correct output:

```
    $time = 1490914800;

    $day = date('j', $time);
    $month = date('n', $time);
    $year = date('Y', $time);

    $i = 1;
    while($i < 12)
    {
        if($month == 12)
        {
            $month = 1;
            $year++;
        }else{
            $month++;
        }

        $useDay = $day;

        if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) $useDay = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));

        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $useDay, $year);

        echo date('d/m/Y', $time).'<bR>';
        $i++;
    }
```